# Truth About Electrical Conductors

Tags: electromagnetism

could you please clarify this, do electrical conductors for example copper power lines in our streets or power lines in the walls or a speaker cable require time with current flowing through them for the conductors to work at their optimum? In other words in the first 10% or so of the conductors being used would they measure any different 50% of the way through the life expectancy of per conductor? 
example only

Comment: There may be aging effects from corrosion, local heating (bad in general for power distribution), or mechanical effects. There is no need to 'condition' wires to carry current. But your question is quite unclear.

Comment: "in the first 10%" of what? Of the conductors lifetime? Of the length of the conductor?

Comment: It takes time from the instant of turn-on until the load has the voltage and current settled following the transient. As aging modifies the quality of conductors and contacts the effective load on the line can change its resistance, capacitance and inductance thus the length of transient, as well.

Comment: Beppi, you wouldn't by chance be thinking of the claims by audiophiles and the high-end audio industry that [electrical cables require a break-in time](https://www.moon-audio.com/break-in-time) to "sound their best"?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no time delay in a metallic conductor to conduction current flow when an electric field is applied as long as you do not go to extremely short time scales. However, there might be a time delay with a time constant $\tau=L/R$ due to the self inductance $L$ and resistance $R$ of a circuit when the voltage source is switched on. This plays a role, e.g., when a power net is switched on after an outage.